# How close does the pressure switch need to be to the tank

Tags: water-pressure

We recently had a well installed (350 ft.) The pressure switch is set directly above the pump and the tank 2*3 feet from the switch. We wanted the tank behind the house, so we moved it.

It is approximately 8-10 feet from the switch. The water ran fine while we were checking the plumbing that was installed. When we tried to run the dirt and sediment from the well, the pump ran for a few minutes then quit pumping. The pressure switch could be heard clicking but no water would come. The well guy came out and said there was water pressure but the tank is too far from the pressure switch and we have to move it back. He says it can't be more than 4 feet from the switch.

Is this true and can we do something else besides moving the tank back?

Comment: It appears that you have your answer...you just don't like it.

Comment: You could pay another well-drilling company to come out and verify the first company's statement, or... you could lump it. :( (Warning: Not a well expert:) Of course, you could move the switch closer to the tank's new location, but that could create other problems.

Comment: Moving the switch creates no problems. A need to change the wiring, but that should not be a problem - it's just a logical consequence of moving the tank.

Answer (score 3):

If the tank is too far from the switch, the pump fires up, the pressure at the switch rises, the pump shuts off, the pressure drops, the pump switches on... that's why it was clicking.

Options:

- Relocate the switch; mine is 300 feet from the pump - it does not need to be near *the pump*. It needs to be near *the tank*. This is the obvious and most correct solution.
- Put *another* pressure tank near the switch and leave the one behind the house - the tank there will provide some buffer to allow time to put pressure into the house tank as well, as opposed to the thrashing you experienced with no tank near the switch. More pressure tank capacity is pretty much always a good thing for a well system.